# Socket connection test, not working and receive data from hyperterminal

Tags: android, sockets

1. I am creating a socket connection in android eclipse for receiving data first i need to test the connection but the page is not opening on my app, i use a listactivity for my classes.
2. I want to receive data from my pc(hyperterminal), i have connected a hardware device to my computer which behaves like a router and i want to connect my android phone to the router via Wifi and receive data on my phone as i type on the hyperterminal.

`package com.exa.bullseye;`

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ScrollView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;

public class WifiReceive extends Activity {
    EditText ip;
    EditText s_port;
    Button connect;

    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
      {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.wifireceive);
        ip = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ip));
        s_port = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.port));

 connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                try {
            String address = ip.getText().toString();


            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            int port = Integer.parseInt(s_port.getText().toString());

            // Creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port
            // number at the specified IP address. Blocks until the connection succeeds.

            Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            socket.close();

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Host not found",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I/O Exception",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   

    }
 });
      }
}
```